# How to write a script to accept any number of command line arguments? (UNIX, BASH)

Tags: unix, bash, script

I have a script that I want to accept any number of command line arguments.

So far I have

```
if [ -O $1 ] ; then
  echo "you are the owner of $1"
else
  echo "you are not the owner of $1"
fi
```

Obviously if I wanted the script to only accept one argument this would work but what would work for ANY number of arguments.

```
ex.  ./script f f1 f2 f3
```

Comment: If something answered your question, can you mark it as the answer (click the checkmark)? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

One possible way to do what you want involves `$@`, which is an array of all the arguments passed in.

```
for item in "$@"; do
  if [ -O "$item" ]; then
    echo "you are the owner of $item"
  else
    echo "you are not the owner of $item"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Um, see what happens when you run `script "arg with spaces"`.  It may or may not be relevant to your situation.  Once you're done, put doublequotes around `$@` and `$item`.

Comment: Good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on exactly what you want to do, but look into `$*`, `$@`, and `shift`.

Answer (score 2):

"$@" does not solve his problem of "ANY number of arguments". there is a limit in how long a commandline can be (http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/). a better way to read in "unlimited arguments" is via STDIN:

```
prg_which_creates_arguments | while read a; do \
    echo "do something with $a"; \
done
```

just create the arguments and pipe them one after another at the code which is doing something with them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script you wanted

```
while test -n "$1"; do
  echo $1
  shift
done
```

If you input:

```
script arg1 arg2 arg3
```

your output will be

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
```